# Apache Lucene & Solr

Tags: java, solr, lucene

Дали таску имплементовать данные технологие, начал смотреть что это и столкнулся с тем, что у всех *обучающих статьях* разбрасываються такими словами как `запрос, индексация, анализатор, нечеткие совпадения, токены, документы`как буд-то все кто смотрит на эти технологии первый раз должен сразу понять что они значат в даном контексте. 
Может кто-то подскажет значение этих слов в контексте Солара или дасть ссылку на ресурсы где это можно почитать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

На официальных ресурсах все термины есть.
Странно что вы не нашли...

Вот парочка ссылок:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Solr+Glossary

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTerminology